Problemas ssh coral dev mini
tengo una google coral dev mini para un proyecto, el caso es que el usb de datos que tiene me hace falta para otra cosa y por ende no puedo usar mdt para conectarme con ella. Entonces lo que había pensado es en conectarme por ssh a esta, por lo tanto he generado mi par de claves con ssh keygen y he añadido la clave pública a la coral dev mini ~/.ssh/authorized_keys . El caso es que cuando me intento conectar por ssh me da el siguiente error y ya no se que puede ser ni que hacer para solventarlo:

mendel@192.168.0.106: Permission denied (publickey).

